# Is there any way of runnning a line of code in octave without highlighting it?

Tags: octave, octave-gui

In Rstudio you can run the code of the current line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. In octave (I'm using 8.3.0) you can do something similar by highlighting the text and then press <kbd>F9</kbd>, but is there a way to do this in a single button instead of having to reach my mouse or use other shortcut keys to highlight the text first?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bot The question is perfectly clear, I just don't think there's a way to do what the OP wants without highlighting the line.

Comment: @beaker
Oh well, thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, no, the question is not that clear. I had to think twice to guess it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Octave does not have this feature.  As you said, you can run a highlighted code block using `F9`.  If you are currently in debug mode, you can run the current line of code that you are paused on with the F10 key (or use the Step button or menu option).  But there is no current method to just run the full line of code at the current cursor location in the editor window, which I believe is the feature you're requesting. This would be an interesting feature that some might find valuable in their workflows. Identifying a key or key combination that wouldn't collide with other functions might require some thought.  Perhaps `CTRL-F9` or similar would work.  I would encourage you to create a Feature Request report over at [bugs.octave.org](https://bugs.octave.org).  It might not be a high priority request, but if it gains enough interest there's a possibility someone would pick it up to implement.  If you do so, please link back the bug report to this question.